# PHP: throw new Exception после Fatal Error

Tags: php, исключения

Пишу свой класс-обработчик ошибок, в конструкторе реализую следующие обработчики:

```
    set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
    set_exception_handler([$this, 'exceptionHandler']);

    ob_start();
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'fatalErrorHandler']);
```

В каждом из этих методов я кидаю новое исключение, например:

```
public function fatalErrorHandler()
{
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ( !empty($error) && $this->isFatalError($error['type']) ) {

        ob_get_clean();
        throw new ErrorException($error['message'], $error['type']);

    } else {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

Класс ErrorException является внуком базового \Exception:

```
class ErrorException extends Exception
{
    const RESPONSE_CODE = 500;
}

class Exception extends \Exception { /* +новые функции */ }
```

**Проблема:** когда тестирую обработчик фатальных ошибок, например, при вызове несуществующей функции вылетает фатальная ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught lynx\core\handlers\ErrorException: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method **Error::array()** in vendor\lynx\core\ErrorHandler.php:124 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: lynx\core\ErrorHandler->exceptionHandler(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\smart-as.dev\vendor\lynx\core\ErrorHandler.php on line 110
```

То есть в обработчик исключений приходит не выкинутый мной ErrorException, а объект Error. Понятно, что он тоже потомок Throwable, но почему он то приходит?

Если кидать исключение объекта глобального \Exception то аналогично - в `exeptionHandler` (код ниже) приходит тот же Error. Не могу понять в чем проблемо, чего-то не понимаю, а нагуглить не могу.

```
public function exceptionHandler(Exception $e)
{
    $this->error = $e->array();

    $this->displayError($e->getResponseCode());

    $this->logErrors();
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [php 7 видимо  у вас](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php) (см. список параметров, второй абзац)?

Comment: @teran абсолютно верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Согласно документации:](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php)

> `set_exception_handler` — Задает пользовательский обработчик
>   исключений
>
> **Список параметров: $exception_handler**
>
> Имя функции, которая будет вызываться каждый раз, когда выбрасывается неперехватываемое исключение. Функция-обработчик должна
>   принимать один аргумент - объект, представляющий выброшенное
>   исключение. До PHP 7 такая функция выглядит так:
>
> ```
> void handler ( Exception $ex )
> ```
>
> В **PHP 7** большинство внутренних ошибок теперь генерируют исключение, но класса `Error`. Для них так же будет вызываться указанный
>   обработчик исключений. Классы `Error` и `Exception` реализуют интерфейс
>   `Throwable`, соответственно именно его следует использовать в сигнатуре
>   функции-обработчика:
>
> ```
> void handler ( Throwable $ex )
> ```
>
> **Предостережение**
>   Указание типа `Exception` для параметра `ex` в вашей функции-обработчике приведет к проблемам в `PHP 7` из-за измененной
>   иерархии классов исключений.

в общем  в вашем случае, все, как написано в доках, один в один.

Comment: Понял, проблема, видимо, тут: `В PHP 7 большинство внутренних ошибок теперь генерируют исключение, но класса Error.`
Получается для такого рода ошибок я не смогу выкинуть потомка даже класса \Error?

Comment: @rugleb я так понимаю, выкидывать вы можете что угодно, просто работать с ним надо будет через `Throwable`, ну и дальше проверять реальный тип и при необходимости приводить явно.

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php):

> В PHP 7 большинство внутренних ошибок теперь генерируют исключение, но класса Error. Для них так же будет вызываться указанный обработчик исключений. Классы Error и Exception реализуют интерфейс Throwable, соответственно именно его следует использовать в сигнатуре функции-обработчика

Соответственно в моей ситуации в принципе срабатывал **сначала** `exceptionHandler`, в который приходил объект `Error`. А я же думал, что это пораждается `fatalErrorHandler`'ом.