# PHP: не удается выкинуть исключение в обработчике ошибок

Tags: php, исключения

Вопрос является продолжением проблемы описанной [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729760/php-throw-new-exception-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-fatal-error#comment1106389_729762).

Пишу класс обработчика ошибок на PHP7. Установка обработчиков ошибок:

```
    set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
    set_exception_handler([$this, 'exceptionHandler']);

    ob_start();
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'fatalErrorHandler']);
```

Сами обработчики:

```
public function fatalErrorHandler()
{
    ob_clean();
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ( !empty($error) && $this->isFatalError($error['type']) ) {
        throw new ErrorException($error['message'], $error['type']);
    }

    throw new ErrorException('Error');
}
```

и

```
public function exceptionHandler(\Throwable $e)
{
    $this->error  = [
        'code'    => $e->getCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        'file'    => $e->getFile(),
        'line'    => $e->getLine()
    ];

    $this->displayError();

    $this->log();
}
```

Класс ErrorException - потомок Exception - потомка базового \Exception. Там добавлено пару методов.

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, PHP просто жалуется на строку, входящую в конструктор первым аргументом. Аналогично, если кидать базовый \Exception.
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

> Регистрирует функцию callback, которая выполнится после завершения
>   работы скрипта или при вызове функции exit().

Т.е. всё, работа скрипта завершилась, исключение ловить некому.

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php):

> В PHP 7 большинство внутренних ошибок теперь генерируют исключение, но класса Error. Для них так же будет вызываться указанный обработчик исключений. Классы Error и Exception реализуют интерфейс Throwable, соответственно именно его следует использовать в сигнатуре функции-обработчика

Проблема оказалась в другом:

В моей ситуации в принципе срабатывал **сначала** `exceptionHandler`, в который приходил объект `Error`. А я же думал, что это пораждается `fatalErrorHandler`'ом.